# How to create an executable file for mac osx from jar file while staying on my windows machine

Tags: java, windows, macos, jar

I am a windows user and I developed a java application. I have a jar file and I have converted that jar to exe for windows. But now I want to send this application to mac users. But I can't figure out how can I do this on my windows. Basically I want to create an executable file for mac from the jar file and I have to stay on windows. Becuase I don't have mac installed.